# SSH2_EXEC() Command failed

Tags: php, command, ssh2-exec

I have successed connected and authorized via ssh2 functions.
But I can't exec command via ssh2_exec() function.

Notoriously get this error:

```
ssh2_exec(): Unable to request command execution on remote host
```

I was trying pass '/bin/ls' 'ls -l' nothing works.
Also I have changed user and getting the same error.

EDIT:

I have changed remote host and all works as expected.
How to set up first host? User name that I'm using in credentials has bash shell enabled. So I might log in via putty and run same command that I can't via PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted!

Problem was that I have default port 22 assigned to SFTP service that's why I was successfuly connecting to remote host but I could not execute command.

SSH listening on port 23 on that problematic machine, so I changed my script to port 23 and all works as expected now.